# Complex aggregate command MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have tons of documents in a Mongo database with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "birthDate" : "1978-08-09",
        "name" : "Peter"
},
    "value" : {
        "types" : {
            "euro" : 90,
            "unknown" : 2,
            "dollar" : 3
        }
    }
}
```

Not all documents contain all types (i.e.: some of them only have `euro` or don't have the `unknown` field).

I want to count the number of occurrences of each `type` for a specific name with the aggregate framework.

I have this:

```
db.collection.aggregate({$match: {_id : {name:"John"}}}, {$group: {_id: '', euro: {$sum: '$value.types.euro'}, dollar: {$sum: '$value.types.dollar'}, unknown: {$sum: '$value.types.unknown'}}})
```

But it is returning:

```
{ "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }
```

My question is: How can I count the `type` of each `coin` for a specific `name` with the Mongo's aggregate framework? Would it be also possible to get a list for every name in the form:

```
"result" : [
    {
        "name" : "Peter",
        "dollar" : 1,
        "euro" : 12,
        "unknown" : 4

    }
]

"result" : [
    {
        "name" : "John",
        "dollar" : 4,
        "euro" : 10,
        "unknown" : 3

    }
]
```

I am using MongoDB with the Java driver, so if the answer is in Java code it would be perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query to group by name & count coins :

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {$group : {_id : "$_id.name", 
             dollar : {$sum : "$value.types.dollar"}, 
             euro : {$sum : "$value.types.euro"}, 
             unknown : {$sum : "$value.types.unknown"}}}
)
```

Also if you want to find the number of coins for specific person you can use following query :

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {$match : {"_id.name" : "John"}},
  {$group : {_id : "$_id.name", 
             dollar : {$sum : "$value.types.dollar"}, 
             euro : {$sum : "$value.types.euro"}, 
             unknown : {$sum : "$value.types.unknown"}}}
)
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for.
Now I'm wondering: would it be possible to only take the results which birthdate is between two dates? i.e. the exact same results from the first request but only those between, for example, 1980-07-05 and 1985-08-05

Comment: you can update $match query as {$match : {"_id.name" : "John", "_id.birthDate" : {$gte : "1980-07-05", $lte : "1985-08-05"}}}

Comment: nice, now the problem is that the date is actually stored like this:
`ISODate("1980-08-05T22:00:00Z")`. Those $gte don't seem to really work, I get `{"result"` `:` `[` `],` `"ok"` `:` `1` `}`
when I update $match with `{$match` `:` `{"_id.name"` `:` `"John",` `"_id.birthDate"` `:` `{$gte` `:` `'ISODate("1980-07-5")',` `$lte` `:` `'ISODate("1985-08-05")'}}}`

Answer (score 1):

To count the `type` of each `coin` for a specific `name`, you can do that :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $match: {'_id.name' : "John"}
}, 
{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        euro: {$cond: [ { $eq: [ '$value.types.euro', undefined ]} , 0, 1 ]},
        dollar: {$cond: [  { $eq: [ '$value.types.dollar', undefined ]} , 0, 1 ]},
        unknown: {$cond: [ { $eq: [ '$value.types.unknown', undefined ]}, 0, 1 ]}
    }  
},
{
    $group: {_id: "$_id.name", euro: {$sum: '$euro'}, dollar: {$sum: '$dollar'}, unknown: {$sum: '$unknown'}}
}
])
```

Comment: Should this be equivalent to the second query that @parvin wrote? The results are very different

Comment: No it's not equivalent to the second query that @parvin wrote. My query count how many times each type (euro, dollar and unknow) are present in all the document with _id.name = 'John'. It's not a $sum of the value of the type. I hope it's clear, my english is not very good :)

Comment: Ok yes I get it! I was looking more for @parvin's one then. Thank you though